# error for retrieving an images from firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am having this error while deleting an image from application

> E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be
>   parsed.

This i my code i write it for deletion

**Images_Actvity.java:**

```
public class Images_Avctivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Image_adapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Image_adapter mAdapter;

    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

    private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private ValueEventListener mDBListener;

    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_images__avctivity);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new Image_adapter(Images_Avctivity.this, mUploads);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Images_Avctivity.this);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUploads.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Images_Avctivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Normal click at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWhatEverClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Whatever click at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
        final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

        StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
        imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(Images_Avctivity.this, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
    }
}
```

This is adpater code:

**Image_adapter.java:**

```
 public class Image_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Image_adapter.ImageViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
        private List<Upload> mUploads;
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;

        public Image_adapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
            mContext = context;
            mUploads = uploads;
        }

        @Override
        public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
            return new ImageViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
            holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mUploads.size();
        }

        public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
                View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
            public TextView textViewName;
            public ImageView imageView;

            public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        mListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
                MenuItem doWhatever = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Do whatever");
                MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

                doWhatever.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case 1:
                                mListener.onWhatEverClick(position);
                                return true;
                            case 2:
                                mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(int position);

            void onWhatEverClick(int position);

            void onDeleteClick(int position);
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use this getStorage() for referenceFromUrl FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getStorage().getReferenceFromUrl(fileURL);

Comment: Please provide database structure

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: i have already added a data structure .... i can upload my images...nut problem is while retrieving that data into an my app

Answer (score 0):

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***********************-5fac-45b6-bbda-ed4e8a3a62ab");
storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() { 
@Override 
public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
    // File deleted successfully 
    Log.e("firebasestorage", "onSuccess: deleted file");
    } 
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
@Override 
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred! 
    Log.e("firebasestorage", "onFailure: did not delete file");
    } 
});
```